# How to style lightning grid and icon like this photo?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-card

I am trying to get a lightning grid with lightning cards similar to this example below. I have my wireframe and the actual image. It seems that there can be more cards you can scroll through using the arrow buttons.

[image]

Here is the code I have so far. It is close but has some issues. The height of the cards aren't uniform. Is there a way to get this more closely aligned with the original image?

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-box">
        <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-card>
                    <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
                        <lightning-layout-item>
                            <img src={trailheadLogoUrl} alt="Trailhead logo" />
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                            <p>Welcome, Trailblazer!</p>
                            <p><br></p>
                            <div>
                            </div>
                            <p><br></p>
                            <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Learn Salesforce" target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </lightning-layout>
                </lightning-card>
        </div>
        
        <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-card>
                    <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
                        <lightning-layout-item>
                            <img src={trailheadLogoUrl} alt="Trailhead logo" />
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                            <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                            <p>Health Check</p>
                            <p><br></p>
                            <div class="slds-progress-bar slds-progress-bar_circular" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="75" role="progressbar">
                                <span class="slds-progress-bar__value" style="width:75%">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <p><br></p>
                            <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="View More Details" target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
                        </lightning-layout-item>
                    </lightning-layout>
                </lightning-card>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-card padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <img src={trailheadLogoUrl} alt="Trailhead logo" />
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                        <p>Welcome, Trailblazer!</p>
                        <p><br></p>
                        <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Learn Salesforce" target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </lightning-card>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-card padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <img src={trailheadLogoUrl} alt="Trailhead logo" />
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                        <p>Welcome, Trailblazer!</p>
                        <p><br></p>
                        <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Learn Salesforce" target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </lightning-card>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col">
            <lightning-card padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                        <img src={trailheadLogoUrl} alt="Trailhead logo" />
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                        <p>Welcome, Trailblazer!</p>
                        <p><br></p>
                        <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Learn Salesforce" target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </lightning-card>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Update: Progress thanks to Caspar
[image]

Comment: Changed my answer - should get you a lot closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media object. Media objects pad the left image nicely and arrange everything the way you want.

**EDIT**: Made changes so children fill their parent.

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-box">
  
  
    <div class="slds-col" style="align-self: stretch;">
      <article class="slds-card" style="height:100%">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
          <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
              <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_large">
                <lightning-icon class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-report" icon-name="standard:report">
                </lightning-icon>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
              <h3>
                <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate">Welcome, Trailblazer!</span>
              </h3>

              <lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Learn Salesforce" target="_blank">
              </lightning-formatted-url>

              <br>

              <lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Another URL" target="_blank">
              </lightning-formatted-url>

              <br>

              <lightning-formatted-url value="https://trailhead.com" label="Yet Another URL" target="_blank">
              </lightning-formatted-url>


            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
    
    <!-- repeat this same div for more -->

  </div>
</template>
```

The above makes this:

[image]

Comment: Looks awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Now of course you will need to work out the horizontal positioning of each... but that could get fiddly, so I didn't have a look at that.

Comment: It's looking fantastic. Updated my post to include what it looks like thanks to your help.